# Can you override superclass method in child to do nothing?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have a parent class and several child classes. I do not want the variable "rotation" to be anything other than 0 for one of the child classes. Is it bad practice to override the methods in that one child class?

```
public class Parent {

    public Parent(double rotation) {
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }

    private double rotation = 0;

    public double getRotation() {
        return rotation;
    }

    public void setRotation(double rotation) {
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }

}



public class RebelChild extends Parent {

    public RebelChild () {
        super(0);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void setRotation(double rotation) {
        // do nothing
    }

}
```

Comment: I wonder if you would rather throw an exception within the `setRotation(...)` method, to warn the caller that something exceptionally bad is occurring.

Comment: Maybe an `UnsupportedOperationException` would be relevant in that case ?

Comment: If it's possible: Yes, it's possible. If it's a good idea: I think this is a sign that your class hierarchy has a design flaw. If `RebelChild` should not be able to rotate, then ideally it should not have a `setRotation` method at all - it should have a different superclass than `Parent` which does not have a `setRotation` method, so that it's also not necessary to override it to do nothing.

Comment: Yes, this ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ what @Jesper said

Comment: @Jesper I suggest you make an Answer of your Comment. And perhaps add a mention of mix-ins by using multiple interfaces if appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find yourself in a situation like this, when a method that exists in a superclass is not appropriate for a subclass, then that's a sign that there is something wrong with the design of your class hierarchy.

There should be an "is a" relationship between subclasses and superclasses. This means that an instance of a subclass (such as `RebelChild` in your example) *is an* instance of its superclass(es): a `RebelChild` object *is a* `Parent` object. This is the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

If one of the methods of the superclass is not appropriate for the subclass, then you are violating this principle. It means that you cannot treat a `RebelChild` object like a `Parent` object.

If the method `setRotation` is not appropriate for a `RebelChild` object, then it should not be a subclass of `Parent`.

When programming, you want to catch errors as early as possible. It is much better to have errors show up when you're compiling than at runtime - that way you'll discover errors much quicker. So, it's better to design your class hierarchy in such a way that the `setRotation` method is not available at all on `RebelChild` objects rather than overriding the method to do nothing, or throwing an exception.

Consider a design like this:

```
public class Thing {
    // methods that are appropriate for any kind of Thing
}

public class RotatableThing extends Thing {
    public double getRotation() { ... }
    public void setRotation(double rotation) { ... }
}

// A specific kind of Thing that can be rotated
public class Something extends RotatableThing {
    // ...
}

// RebelChild is a Thing that cannot be rotated
public class RebelChild extends Thing {
}
```

Alternatively, make `Rotatable` an interface:

```
public interface Rotatable {
    double getRotation();
    void setRotation(double rotation);
}

// Something is a Thing that can also be rotated
public class Something extends Thing implements Rotatable {
    // ...
}

// RebelChild cannot be rotated so it does not implement Rotatable
public class RebelChild extends Thing {
    // ...
}
```